# Kubernetes Kubelet says that DNS is not set with MissingClusterDNS (SkyDNS)

Tags: dns, kubernetes, skydns

I've install a Kubernetes 1.2.4 on 3 minons/master (1 master/minion, 2 minions) and installed the SkyDNS addons. After fixing SSL cert problems, I know have SkyDNS working. But kubeletes still says that I didn't set cluster-dns and cluster-domain.

(see edits at the bottom)

But you can see `--cluster-dns=192.168.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local`:

```
ps ax | grep kubelet
18717 ?        Ssl    0:04 /opt/kubernetes/bin/kubelet --logtostderr=true --v=0 --address=0.0.0.0 --port=10250 --hostname-override=k8s-minion-1 --api-servers=http://k8s-master:8080 --allow-privileged=false  --cluster-dns=192.168.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local
```

Launching this pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
```

I see:

```
kubectl describe pod busybox
7m      7m      2   {kubelet k8s-master.XXX}                    Warning     MissingClusterDNS   kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to DNSDefault policy.
```

I restarted kubelete services before to launch this pod, and I have no other pod running.

If I launch docker container using "--dns" option:

```
docker run --rm -it --dns 192.168.0.10 busybox nslookup cluster.local
Server:    192.168.0.10
Address 1: 192.168.0.10

Name:      cluster.local
Address 1: 192.168.0.10
Address 2: 172.16.50.2
Address 3: 192.168.0.1
Address 4: 172.16.96.3


docker run --rm -it --dns 192.168.0.10 busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
search XXX YYYY 
nameserver 192.168.0.10
```

That's absolutly normal (I've hidden my client dns)

But the pod says something else:

```
kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup cluster.local
Server:    XXX.YYY.XXX.YYY
Address 1: XXX.YYYY.XXXX.YYY XXX.domain.fr

nslookup: can't resolve 'cluster.local'
error: error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: Error executing in Docker Container: 1
```

I tried to set "--dns" option to the docker daemon, but the error is the same.

See that logs:

```
kubectl get  pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-dns-v11-osikn   4/4       Running   0          13m
```

And:

```
kubectl logs kube-dns-v11-osikn kube2sky --namespace=kube-system
I0621 15:44:48.168080       1 kube2sky.go:462] Etcd server found: http://127.0.0.1:4001
I0621 15:44:49.170404       1 kube2sky.go:529] Using https://192.168.0.1:443 for kubernetes master
I0621 15:44:49.170422       1 kube2sky.go:530] Using kubernetes API <nil>
I0621 15:44:49.170823       1 kube2sky.go:598] Waiting for service: default/kubernetes
I0621 15:44:49.209691       1 kube2sky.go:660] Successfully added DNS record for Kubernetes service.
```

<strike>"Using kubernetes API `<nil>`" is a problem, isn't it ?</strike>
edit: I forced kube-master-url in the pod to let kube2sky contacting the master.

```
kubectl logs kube-dns-v11-osikn skydns --namespace=kube-system
2016/06/21 15:44:50 skydns: falling back to default configuration, could not read from etcd: 100: Key not found (/skydns/config) [10]
2016/06/21 15:44:50 skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]
2016/06/21 15:44:50 skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:53 [rcache 0]
```

Note this too:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces 
NAMESPACE     NAME                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       busybox              1/1       Running   0          17m
kube-system   kube-dns-v11-osikn   4/4       Running   0          18m
```

So I've got no problem with skydns.

I'm sure that the problem comes from kubelet, I've tried to remove /var/lib/kubelet and restart the entire cluster. I've tried to restart kubelete services before and after installing dns also. I changed docker configuration, removed "--dns" option afterwoard, and I've got the same behaviour: Docker + dns is ok, Kubelet gives a MissingClusterDNS error saying that kubelet has got no configured cluster dns.

So please... Help (one more time :) )

---

EDITS:
- now kube2sky doesn't complain about `<nil>` api version forcing kube2sky option
- I can force nslookup to use my sky DNS:

```
kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 192.168.0.10
Server:    192.168.0.10
Address 1: 192.168.0.10

Name:      kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 192.168.0.1
```

But the "MissingClusterDNS" error remains on pod creation, as if kubelet doesn't the startup options "--cluster-dns" and "--cluster-domain"

@Brendan Burns:

```
kubectl get services --namespace=kube-system
NAME       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns   192.168.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   12m
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. In the future, questions that are similar to this should be asked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed my problem... Shame on me (or not).

I've taken kubelet sources to understand what happends and now I found.

In the "kubelet" file, I set:

```
KUBE_ARGS="--cluster-dns=10.10.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local"
```

And the log I added in source says that "cluster-dns" option as this value:

```
10.10.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local
```

That's mainly because the config file is interpreted by SystemD as a "bash environment vars" so KUBE_ARGS is "one argument", and it's badly parsed by kubelet service.

The solution is to split variable in two and change kubelet.service file to use vars. After a call to `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart kubelet` everything is ok.

I opened an issue here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27722 where I explain that the comment in example config file is ambiguous and/or the arguments are not parsed as expected.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem but splitting the vars and restarting the kubelet service doesn't do it for me `            ${KUBELET_DNS}      \
            ${KUBELET_DOMAIN}      \`

Comment: Can you open a new discussion and link it here? I'll take a look.

Comment: I fixed it somehow, with the above solution. My current config looks like this  `KUBELET_DNS=--cluster-dns={{ cluster_dns }}

KUBELET_DOMAIN=--cluster-domain=cluster.local` I think the problem was I was leaving a space between the '=' sign and the template variable.

Comment: Yes. Environment files are bash. So spaces are not allowed after equal signs. Glade you've found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the DNS service with the right IP address?

What does `kubectl get services --namespace=kube-system` show?

Comment: As you can see, the docker command with the ip address as dns works. I'm not at office right now but I will give you the answer tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the command returns the right DNS address - I just made the entire installation locally on 3 centos on KVM.

Comment: I added the command output, the DNS IP is ok - you can see edits

Comment: In my case, I use microk8s. I face the issue during the "deployment" of elasticsearch on microk8s version 1.14.  To answer,  `kubectl get services --namespace=kube-system` returns no result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `microk8s`:

1. Inspect `microk8s` service status using `microk8s status`:

```
ubuntu@staging-1:~$ microk8s status
microk8s is running
dns: disabled
...
```

2. Enable dns service using: `microk8s enable dns:x.x.x.x`